# Можно ли найти коммит в git по строчке?

Tags: репозиторий, git

Есть репозиторий в гит с долгой, обширной и печальной историей.
В один файл в одном из коммитов добавляется строчка, которая ВСЕ ЛОМАЕТ.
Я хочу найти этот коммит и покарать негодяя. Могу ли я это сделать родными средствами git?
Если да, то как?

Строчка уникальна, похожих в файле точно нету.
В файле постоянно происходят массированные изменения, поэтому вдумчиво покурить в историю не помогло (разбираться, как автоматически парсить историю, влом).
Номер строчки, разумеется, может меняться.

Comment: Может, это поможет?

[Stackoverflow: How to grep (search) committed code in the git history?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2928584/how-to-grep-search-committed-code-in-the-git-history)

Comment: А меня одного волнует, что случилось после того, как виновник был найден?

Comment: в подобных разбирательствах, вначале нужно разобраться, кто сделал бяку, но сделать вид, что ты ещё не понял. И только после этого можно говорить о наказании. А то можно случайно на себя навести.

Comment: @Volt, может лучше разобраться с бардаком, при котором в один файл постоянно вносятся изменения (к тому же, похоже, не оттестированные) *несколькими разными* программистами?

Или просто уйти из такой команды...

Comment: @Etki, я подошел к виновнику и несколько минут покапал ему на мозг по поводу того, что свои изменения надо проверять. А что, есть другие варианты?

@avp, разбираться надо, конечно, но менеджеры считают, что это неважно и на это нет времени.   
Собственно, я оттуда почти ушел =)

Comment: @etki, лично я сначала выясняю какие цели декларировались в описании коммита, и насколько изменение релевантно заявленному. Далее или выношу решение о необходимости дополнительного обучения/разъяснения (чаще всего) или доношу сведения о систематических нарушениях со стороны сотрудника до вышестоящего начальства.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Есть такая штука как [bisect](http://git-scm.com/book/ru/%D0%98%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D1%8B-Git-%D0%9E%D1%82%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D1%81-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%89%D1%8C%D1%8E-Git) - она позволяет искать проблему методом деления пополам, который, как известно, имеет логарифмическую сложность. Суть: для начала указываете коммит, который точно сломан, потом коммит, который точно исправен. Гит делает checkout в коммит, который находится где-то посредине. В этот момент можно запустить тесты, посмотреть ручками и сказать git - этот коммит хорош или плох. И так до победного конца. И это будет быстро. Даже если там 1024 коммита, нужно будет сделать не более 10-11 просмотров кода.

Но если это просто одна строка, то можно прикрутить grep, который будет проверять наличие этой строки. Тогда процесс пойдет ещё быстрее.

```
git bisect start  # стартуем
git bisect bad    # текущий коммит - плохой
git bisect good <hash> # а вот коммит с таким хешем/тегом - хорош.

git bisect run grep 'string' * -rsq # поехали искать.
```

git распечатает информацию по первому коммиту, который содержит указанную строку.

И не забыть в конце поисков выполнить `git bisect reset`.

Comment: Благодарю, конкретно сейчас мне достаточно было blame, но bisect это еще круче и пригодится в будущем

Comment: С bisect есть одна сложность. Если между good и bad история несколько раз разветвлялась и сливалась обратно, то с первого раза мы скорее всего найдем merge, потом придётся повторить ещё раз для ветки. А может и не раз, если история совсем запутанная.

Answer (score 6):

Если это строчка, и её никто потом не менял, то:

```
git blame
```

Answer (score 5):

Есть опция -S для git-log, которая показвает все коммиты, добавляющие или удаляющие искомую строку:

```
git log -S 'if (x = 5) {'
```

Answer (score 1):

Если файл и текст известны и нужно найти негодяя - просто делаете `git blame` и получите для каждой строки файла дату последнего коммита, хэш и автора.