# Как в Git посмотреть изменения именно по конкретной строке?

Tags: git, git-log

По номеру строки на сейчас все же получить кто и когда делал изменения?
Просто поиск текста не надежный вариант, в одном файле (да еще и где пол сотни тысяч строк) может быть одинаковые строки кода, разными людьми (copypaste).

А если эту строку уже исправили то тоже, покажет только последний кто, а до этого кто уже нет :(
**--graph** подходит, но не по тексту строки бы, а точно указать что на текущий момент именно по этому номеру строки или еще чему.

Comment: а метод поиска деления пополам - не помогло?

Comment: Нужно не когда менялся файл, а когда и кем менялась конкретная строка в файле

Comment: вам ответили, используя `blame` - он сам находит и прописывает все данные кто и кода изменил каждую строчку. *"Commits include lots of metadata in addition to the contents and message, like the author, timestamp, and more."*

Comment: если речь про blame браузере на гитлабе то увы:
1. файл в в дестяки тысяч строк он мягко говоря помирает
2. выдает явно не то, потому по той последней задаче которую показывает, потом открываешь и там нет таких изменений.

Если речь про через командную строку, то вопрос по сути был можно ли найти по номеру строки все изменения. Тоесть указал и получил как в svn или на крайний случай mercurial, я просто пытаюсь понять, получается просто одним действием (без серьезных изысканий) по быстрому не понять кто и когда менял строку конкретную?

Comment: Просто по работе много разных запросов и нужно по каждому найти и прикрепить по какой задаче делалось, если по каждой заниматься изысканиями то это конечно жестоко со стороны гита будет.

Comment: Чтобы узнать что на 100-ой строчке добавляете аргумент `git blame -L 99,101` пробовали?

Comment: Да, выдает то что и в браузере на гитлабе, только того, кто последний менял эту строку
В идеале часто это и нужно, но бывает что уже изменили, а нужно узнать предыдущий кто изменил, вообще суперски бы получить все коммиты по этой строке

Comment: Эта строка оригинал у нее нет никакого другого автора. Всё нужно делать вручную, переходим на коммит, делаем `log` смотрим коммит перед данным изменением и продолжаем в том-же духе, но ищем совсем **другую** строку. У предыдущей строки уже совсем **другой** автор.

Comment: спасибо, жаль, крайне не удобная система получается, быстро найти кто менял этот код получается проблематично :(

Comment: По строке кто и когда менял получается вообще не узнать, если не заниматься дикими изысканиями.
Если в коде было смещение процедур/функций которое затронуло нужную строку то blame считает что это изменение и показывает этого человека и его коммит, но по факту этот разраб  код сместил но не трогал эту строку вообще.

Answer (score 3):

к тому вопросу, который вас заинтересовал, есть ведь замечательный [ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/363144/178576) про команду `blame` ([man-страница](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-blame)).

в этой команде можно ведь указать (помимо многого прочего) и ревизию. любым из способов, описанных в [man git-rev-parse](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rev-parse).

---

для примера посмотрим, как, когда и кем менялся заголовок в файле [README.md](https://github.com/git/git/tree/221222b278e713054e65cbbbcb2b1ac85483ea89) в исходниках самой программы *git*.

вот так он выглядит после последнего на данный момент коммита:

```
$ head -n 3 README.md 
[![Build status](https://github.com/git/git/workflows/CI/badge.svg)](https://github.com/git/git/actions?query=branch%3Amaster+event%3Apush)

Git - fast, scalable, distributed revision control system
```

когда был изменён последний раз? ага, видим, в 2016-м году, коммитом с хэшем `28513c4f56a`:

```
$ git blame README.md | head -n 3
df7375d7728 README.md (Ævar Arnfjörð Bjarmason 2021-11-23 17:29:09 +0100  1) [![Build status](https://github.com/git/git/workflows/CI/badge.svg)](https://github.com/git/git/actions?query=branch%3Amaster+event%3Apush)
5f7864663bd README.md (Johannes Schindelin     2019-01-29 06:19:32 -0800  2) 
28513c4f56a README.md (Matthieu Moy            2016-02-25 09:37:29 +0100  3) Git - fast, scalable, distributed revision control system
```

а как посмотреть изменение **перед** этим коммитом? ну, как обычно: `хэш^` (см. [man git-rev-parse](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rev-parse)):

```
$ git blame 28513c4f56a^ README.md | head -n 3
4ad21f5d597 README.md (Matthieu Moy      2016-02-25 09:37:26 +0100  1) Git - the stupid content tracker
4ad21f5d597 README.md (Matthieu Moy      2016-02-25 09:37:26 +0100  2) ================================
556b6600b25 README    (Nicolas Pitre     2007-01-17 13:04:39 -0500  3)
```

ага! вот когда ещё присутствовало классическое определение `stupid` в описании программы *git*.

собственно, этим коммитом `4ad21f5d597` файл и был создан, а точнее, переименован из `README`:

```
$ git show --name-status 4ad21f5d597
commit 4ad21f5d5979f7a192c0774881bef340d3cc86a8
Author: Matthieu Moy <git@matthieu-moy.fr>
Date:   Thu Feb 25 09:37:26 2016 +0100

    README: use markdown syntax
    
    This allows repository browsers like GitHub to display the content of
    the file nicely formatted.
    
    Signed-off-by: Matthieu Moy <Matthieu.Moy@imag.fr>
    Signed-off-by: Junio C Hamano <gitster@pobox.com>

R093    README  README.md
M       t/t7001-mv.sh
```

потому `blame` и не покажет, что было **до того** с этим файлом:

```
$ git blame 4ad21f5d597^ README.md
fatal: no such path README.md in 4ad21f5d597^
```

но мы ведь уже знаем, что файл до этого назывался `README`. смотрим **его** историю:

```
$ git blame 4ad21f5d597^ README | head -n 3
8ac866a869a (David Greaves     2005-05-22 18:44:16 +0100  1) ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
6ad6d3d36c5 (Linus Torvalds    2005-04-17 21:52:23 -0700  2) 
48a8c26c625 (Thomas Ackermann  2013-01-21 20:16:20 +0100  3)    Git - the stupid content tracker
```

ну и ещё дальше находим таки тот коммит, которым правил заголовок автор первых версий программы *git*:

```
$ git blame 48a8c26c625^ README | head -n 3
8ac866a869a (David Greaves     2005-05-22 18:44:16 +0100  1) ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
6ad6d3d36c5 (Linus Torvalds    2005-04-17 21:52:23 -0700  2) 
^e83c516331 (Linus Torvalds    2005-04-07 15:13:13 -0700  3)    GIT - the stupid content tracker
```

собственно, это первый коммит в данном репозитории. он и отмечен особым образом — видите крышку перед хэшем?

```
$ git show --shortstat e83c516331
commit e83c5163316f89bfbde7d9ab23ca2e25604af290
Author: Linus Torvalds <torvalds@linux-foundation.org>
Date:   Thu Apr 7 15:13:13 2005 -0700

    Initial revision of "git", the information manager from hell

 11 files changed, 1244 insertions(+)
```

Comment: `blame` - по английски ответственен. *Наследил, поймаем.*